# Simultaneously create attributes and edges (if same attr. exists) in NetworkX

Tags: python-3.5, networkx

After creating nodes in NetworkX, I would like add edges between nodes if both nodes have (at least) one overlapping same attribute.
It seems to be a problem that not all nodes contain the same number of attributes - could this be the case, and if so, how should I solve it?

```
import networkx as nx
from itertools import product

# Mothernodes
M = [('E_%d' % h, {'a': i, 'b': j, 'c': k, 'd': l})
 for h, (i, j, k, l) in enumerate(product(range(2), repeat=4), start=1)]

# children nodes
a = [ (  'a_%d' % i, {'a' : i}) for i in range(0,2)  ]
b = [ (  'b_%d' % i, {'b' : i}) for i in range(0,2)  ]
c = [ (  'c_%d' % i, {'c' : i}) for i in range(0,2)  ]
d = [ (  'd_%d' % i, {'d' : i}) for i in range(0,2)  ]


# graph containing both
M_c = nx.Graph()
M_c.add_nodes_from(M)

ls_children = [a, b, c , d]
for ls_c in ls_children:
    M_c.add_nodes_from(ls_c)

list(M_c.nodes(data=True))[0:20]

[('E_9', {'a': 1, 'b': 0, 'c': 0, 'd': 0}),
 ('d_0', {'d': 0}),
 ('E_10', {'a': 1, 'b': 0, 'c': 0, 'd': 1}),
 ('b_0', {'b': 0}),
 ('E_2', {'a': 0, 'b': 0, 'c': 0, 'd': 1}),
 ('E_1', {'a': 0, 'b': 0, 'c': 0, 'd': 0}),
 ('c_1', {'c': 1}),
 ...
    ] 

# attempting to add edges if one attribute is overlapping/the same: 
for start in M_c.nodes(data=True):
    for end in M_c.nodes(data=True):
       for attr in list(start[1].keys()):
            if start[1][attr] == end[1][attr]:
                M_c.add_edge(start[0] ,end[0] )


 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
 <ipython-input-4-22b88809e853> in <module>()
       2     for end in M_c.nodes(data=True):
       3         for attr in list(start[1].keys()):
 ----> 4             if start[1][attr] == end[1][attr]:
       5                 M_c.add_edge(start[0] ,end[0] )

 KeyError: 'b'
```

EDIT2:

I have now tried to test both start and end for existence of attributes, but I still get an error:

```
for start in M_c.nodes(data=True):
    for end in M_c.nodes(data=True):
        for attr in list(start[1].keys()):
            if start[1][attr]:
                if end[1][attr]:
                    if start[1][attr] == end[1][attr]:
                        M_c.add_edge(start[0], end[0] )
    # Adding an else and continue statement does not affect the error, 
    # even adding three of them, for each if statement
    #        else:
    #            continue

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-32ae2a6095e5> in <module>()
      3         for attr in list(start[1].keys()):
      4             if start[1][attr]:
----> 5                 if end[1][attr]:
      6                     if start[1][attr] == end[1][attr]:
      7                         M_c.add_edge(start[0], end[0] )

KeyError: 'a'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Creating edges between nodes sharing the same attribute value

```
import networkx as nx
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# create nodes
G = nx.Graph()
_ = [G.add_node(i, a=random.randint(1,10), 
                   b=random.randint(1,10), 
                   c=random.randint(1,10)) for i in range(20)]

for node in G.nodes(data=True):
    print(node)
```

[out:]

```
(0, {'a': 10, 'b': 10, 'c': 3})
(1, {'a': 10, 'b': 6, 'c': 2})
(2, {'a': 4, 'b': 5, 'c': 5})
(3, {'a': 5, 'b': 10, 'c': 8})
(4, {'a': 3, 'b': 10, 'c': 8})
(5, {'a': 7, 'b': 1, 'c': 9})
(6, {'a': 10, 'b': 8, 'c': 8})
(7, {'a': 7, 'b': 7, 'c': 2})
(8, {'a': 6, 'b': 3, 'c': 9})
(9, {'a': 1, 'b': 5, 'c': 7})
(10, {'a': 3, 'b': 2, 'c': 8})
(11, {'a': 4, 'b': 1, 'c': 6})
(12, {'a': 3, 'b': 10, 'c': 3})
(13, {'a': 4, 'b': 5, 'c': 3})
(14, {'a': 7, 'b': 10, 'c': 4})
(15, {'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 10})
(16, {'a': 1, 'b': 9, 'c': 1})
(17, {'a': 3, 'b': 8, 'c': 4})
(18, {'a': 6, 'b': 8, 'c': 7})
(19, {'a': 7, 'b': 10, 'c': 4})
```

### Creating edges

```
for start in G.nodes(data=True):
    for end in G.nodes(data=True):
        for attr in list(start[1].keys()):
            if start[1][attr] == end[1][attr]:
                G.add_edge(start[0] ,end[0] )
```

### Plotting the network

```
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G,pos)
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G,pos, font_color='w')
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting_network]

Comment: Thanks @michaelg - I will try this out tonight, thank you so much!

Comment: Thank you again @michaelg, I have edited the question because I have tried your solution and probably I have not explained well enough in my question what I was trying, so I got an error. If you do have time to help, I would be very grateful.

Comment: From your error it seems that you need to test the presence of the attribute in the end node first. For example: `if end[1][attr]:` before testing for equality.

Comment: Thanks again - I've tested the suggestion (both only end[1] as well as including start[1], like shown above in my edited question) but I still get a similar error. Perhaps I am overlooking something?

Comment: I've created a new question, perhaps that's better: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49789975/having-nodes-with-differing-lengths-of-attributes-add-edges-if-1

Comment: Sorry I could not test the solution when I submitted my previous comment. I answered on your second post with a tested response.